# ReactFX Val, how do I get binding for null status?

Tags: java, javafx, reactfx

In JavaFX's `Property` you can obtain a boolean binding for null or non null via `val.isNull()` and `val.isNonNull()`.

What's the equivalence for this in ReactFX?

I've tried:

```
val.map(v -> v == null)
```

But it would return a `Val<Boolean>` with the actual value `null` instead of `true` (which is as expected in other cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
val.map(v -> false).orElseConst(true)
```

will give you what you need.

Comment: Brilliant! But how come it's not baked into the api?

Comment: The use cases where you only care if it's null, but don't care what it's value is, are probably fairly rare. And since it's just one extra call (`orElseConst(true)`) on top of the `map`, it probably doesn't justify the additional API. Also, the general philosophy here is that `null` should represent "no value", rather than "a special value"; `orElse` and `orElseConst` are specifically there for the cases where you want to represent a "special value".

Comment: You can also look at it that `orElseConst` gives you both `isNull()` *and* `isNotNull()` (just reverse `true` and `false`), as well as lots of other useful functionality. So, again, the API trade off (API bloat vs convenience) is not worth it.